# CSS nested element moving when window resized

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a nested element like this;

```
<li style="padding-left: 5%; padding-right: 5%; margin:auto;" >

    <a style="color: black; padding-left:0%; padding-right: 0%;; text-decoration: none;" asp-area="" asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Index" title="Manage">Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</a>

</li>
```

The problem is, on page load the `<a>` element is sticking out of its box which is a `dropdown-menu dropdown-user` class from bootstrap. What confuses me, is when the window is resized, the dropdown then resizes so the element fits. Why is this?

Here is the whole snippet;

```
<li id="LoginPartial">
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using BiggestLoser.Models

@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager

@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
    {
        <form asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout" method="post" id="logoutForm" >
            <ul style="padding:0px; color: black; text-decoration: none;">
                <li style="padding-left: 5%; padding-right: 5%; margin:auto;" >
                    <a style="color: black; padding-left:0%; padding-right: 0%;; text-decoration: none;" asp-area="" asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Index" title="Manage">Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link" style="color: black; padding:0px; text-decoration: none;" ><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Log out</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    } else {
        <ul style="padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px">
            <li><a style="color: black; text-decoration: none;" asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>  Register</a></li>
            <li><a style="color: black; text-decoration: none;" asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>  Log in</a></li>
        </ul>
    }
</li>
```

[EDIT]

I have discovered that it is the padding on the `<a>` element (nested in the `<li`> element) that is causing the problem. It only seems to fit into place once I toggle the padding on and off in Chrome Dev tools. I don't know why. Once the dropdown is closed and reopened, it goes back and does the same thing. I am very confused as to why.

Comment: Some additional context would be helpful. Can you try to recreate the problem as a code snippet, or on jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: not really. My code is very complex, everything is linked together and requires a lot of razor to get working, it would require most of the code to even recreate it.

Comment: I have added the full snippet if it helps